# ¿Cuál es la forma más clara y eficiente de implementar esta comparación en c++?

Tags: c++

Es una comparación simple pero me gustaría evaluar otras formas más claras y eficientes de hacerlo, si de esta manera con ***switch*** o ***if*** anidados u otras opciones.

```
bool ArrayStack<E>::isGrupingCharacter(E element) {
  if (element == '(' || element == ')' || element == '{' || element == '}' || element == '[' || element == ']') {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Las preguntas basadas en opiniones terminan cerradas, así que te invito a leer esto: [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Con respecto a lo otro.  ¿Por qué el tipo de element es `E`? Debería ser de tipo `char`, puesto en las condiciones estás comparando dos caracteres. Lo usual sería usar un **switch**, porque no necesitas estar haciendo comparaciones de forma innecesaria con el *if anidado*, en cambio, con el *switch* se lo hace directo.

Comment: Un consejo: No te obsesiones con la eficiencia hasta que realmente suponga un problema... conseguir una mejora de 1 microsegundo en una tarea que tarda 10 milisegundos es, normalmente, un absurdo y una pérdida de tiempo

Comment: Muchas gracias por sus opiniones...solo quería saber si hay una manera más estética de hacerla...suponiendo que la comparación fuera más extensa creo que un modo mejor seria muy útil que la manera en que lo hice  en cuestión de legibilidad y escritura.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usa la cabecera `<algorithm>` y comprueba si cualquiera de los elementos coincide con el elemento entrante:

```
bool ArrayStack<E>::isGrupingCharacter(E element) {
    constexpr static char elements[] = "(){}[]";
    return std::any_of(std::begin(elements), std::end(elements),
                       [&element](const auto &candidate) { return candidate == element; });
}
```

Al tener todos los elementos candidatos en una variable de texto, es muy fácil de mantener y de depurar. El uso de `any_of` da una clara muestra de intencionalidad.

Pero la plantilla en si es inconsistente: está parametrizada sobre el parámetro `E` que aparentemente es un carácter de tipo arbitrario, pero sólo  se comprueba contra caracteres `char`, si `E` fuese `wchar_t`, `signed char`,  `unsigned char`, `char16_t` o `char32_t` podrías tener problemas.

Comment: Muchas gracias  me sirvió excelente